# How to reverse a mathematical function in python, so that the input can figured from the output?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, binary

I've got this problem. I have this function called "scramble".
It takes two parameters, S, and B. B is a string that is binary ("101010").
I know it can be reversed, because it's been done before.
I'm trying to convert this string into it's unscrambled version

`"1100001110000111000011000010100001110000111000010100001110000010000110010001011001110000101010001011000001000"`
With S being 9.

Here's my first attempt. I've tried multiple variations, but it just won't function, since the opposite of a modulus (which produces a remainder) is division (produces a quotient)

I have S. I just need a way to turn R into B.

```
def unscramble(r, s):
    b = ""
    x = s
    while x < len(r) + s:
        b += r[x / len(r)]
        x += 1
    return b
```

The problem is, it creates a floating number with decimal points, which can't work in slicing.

```
def scramble(b, s):
    r = ""
    x = s
    while x < len(b) + s:
        r += b[x % len(b)]
        x += 1
    return r
```

Comment: Doesn't your 'scramble' function just circular-left-shift your string by `s`? For example, try running `scramble('abcde', 2)` and see what you get. With that knowledge, it should be simple to reverse the scramble.

Comment: @NiayeshIsky This sounds very stupid, but how would I do that? I tried to, and I just ended up with another circular left shift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from output of your scramble function you can figure out how to unscramble.

```
def scramble(b, s):
    r = ""
    x = s
    while x < len(b) + s:
        r += b[x % len(b)]
        x += 1
    return r

def unscramble(r, s):
    b = ""
    x = s
    b = r[-x:]
    b += r[0:-x]
    return b

r = scramble('homer simpson', 2)
print(r)

s= unscramble('mer simpsonho', 2)
print(s)
```

output:

```
mer simpsonho
homer simpson
```